# (No muestra mis imagenes ASP.NET CORE MVC )Not allowed to load local resource: Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Estoy tratando de mostrar un slide de imagenes, en donde tengo almacenada la ruta en mi DB, entiendo que por motivos de seguridad parece ser que chrome no accede o no permite mostrarlas por ser un directorio local en donde estan. Tengo varios registros en mi db, y cada registro tiene una carpeta diferente cuando selecciono un registro en mi vista este deberia de poder tomarlo y mostrarme las imgaenes segun el registro que selecciono.  Como podria acceder a ellas o modificar mi funcion para que no me siga dando problemas?

Ya tengo las carpetas dentro de wwwroot y en mi db unicamente estoy almancenado "el nombre de la carpeta"

Esta es mi funcion

```
    public IActionResult VerArea(int id)
    {
        // Buscar el área por ID en la base de datos
        var area = context.PmAreasPresentacions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);

        if (area != null)
        {
            // Obtener la ruta de la carpeta de imágenes según el área
            var carpetaImagenes = area.RutaCarpeta;

            // Obtener la lista de archivos de imagen en la carpeta
            var imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, carpetaImagenes));

            return View(imagenes);
        }

        // Manejo de error si el área no se encuentra
        return NotFound();
    }
```

Vista

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    @foreach (var rutaImagen in Model)
    {
        <div class="carousel-item @(rutaImagen == Model.First() ? "active" : "")">
            <img src="@Url.Content( rutaImagen)" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen">
        </div>
    }

</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Esto es la misma pregunta que veniamos trabajando... como queda armada la url de las imagenes??? no duplique tu pregunta, agrega la informacion que tengas nueva a la pregunta anterior...